# Angular - Bind input to value in dynamic object

Tags: angular, angular2-template

(Angular Version 5)

I am experimenting with a dynamic object as a store of specific values.

"Values by person by group". Something like this:

```
let store = {
  'groupA':{
    'personA': 1.0,
    'personB': 2.3,
    ...
  },
  'groupB':{
    'personA': 4.1,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Having this structure I can get a specific value like this `store['groupA'][personB]`

Where groupId and personID are new keys which do not exist with the object.

> For above requirement straight forward [(ngModel)] won't work since object structure is not defined.
>   i.e.
>   `<input [(ngModel)]="store[group.id][person.id]">` does not work as the value and the whole structure is undefined.

Do i need to initialize the structure in a special way or bind the value differenttly ?

**My main problem is, that i do not know if there is a value for a given groupId. The ? Operator `(store?[group.id]?[person.id])` should solve my problem, but it is not working with [ ] notation.

Comment: Do you have sample code to show you tried something at least?

Comment: You have two groupA's. Is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry. I noticed, that i do not need an array... I edited my question.

Comment: Problem stays the same. This bindind ``<input [(ngModel)]="store[group.id][person.id]">`` does not work :-( "Cannot read property ... of undefined"

Comment: Works fine for me check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xarzkz?file=src/app/hero-detail/hero-detail.component.html

Comment: I added `[(ngModel)]="hero[propName]"` and in the component `propName = 'name``

Comment: But i have/need two levels of dynamic properties. here[propName][subProbName]...

Comment: @Phillip Done - 2 levels https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xarzkz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-detail%2Fhero-detail.component.html

Comment: Click on Narco in that Demo - you will see `hero.address.city` being accesses as `hero[prop1][prop2]` dynamic properties. Since that works I am interested in why it doe not work for you. Can you put more code in here ?

Answer (score 0):

I created two demos how to work with this problem.
Hope you get what you wanted.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2zjyqf)

Comment: If I'm not wrong he is asking if he wants to add a new groupId and new personID not groupId/personId it already has which is straight forward.

Answer (score -1):

You can Do like following:

## HTML

```
<input type="text" name="my-inp" (change)="chngVl($event,nuId,nuId1)">
```

## TS

```
nuId = 'xxxx';
  nuId1 = 'xxxx1';

  store = {
    'groupA': {
      'personA': 1.0
    },
    'groupB': {
      'personB': 2.3
    },
    'groupC': {
      'personC': 4.1
    }
  };


chngVl(ev,nuId,nuId1){
    if(!this.store[nuId]){
      this.store[nuId] = {};
      this.store[nuId][nuId1] = ev.target.value;
    }else {
      this.store[nuId][nuId1] = ev.target.value;
    }

    console.log("store: ",this.store);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it would not give me a two-way-binding. I need to show the current value (if there is one) and be able to edit it.

Comment: Two way binding is nothing but communication between view<=>controller, [(ngModel)] also has similar implication on its core part

Comment: I knwo, but how would you display the value in your example? store[nuId][nuId1] will not work, as nuId might be undefined.

Comment: nuId can be undefined, is that an issue?  Here you have implementation in your hand you can turn it as the way you like.

Answer (score -1):

Update

After seeing your comments, I realised I misunderstood, however same concept with a bit more logic

Check this demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7icspf

Basically, this caters for dynamic looping through Object.Keys mentioned in the older post along with the map.

First, get all the keys needed

```
let keys = Object.keys(store);
this.keysLvl1 = keys;
this.keysLvl2 = keys.map(x => Object.keys(store[x]));
```

Traverse them in the html

```
<div *ngFor="let key of keysLvl1;let i = index;">
<div *ngFor="let key2 of keysLvl2[i];">
    {{key}}:{{key2}} <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="store[key][key2]" />
</div>
</div>
```

---

I made out a demo, however you can access Javascript Objects in the following manner:

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="store['groupA']['personB']" type="text">
```

Check the demo for the full example using your own JSON structure.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7icspf)

Also.. when working with JS objects for dynamic loading I found keys to very useful, good read here: [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Thanky you. But i knwo how to access object properties. My problem is, that those properties are dynamic. I do not know if 'groupA' is even initialized in the store object.

Comment: In that case, you should use the Object.keys I mentioned at the end, store them in a variable and loop over them :)

Comment: But then i would not be able to initialize it (if it is not there yet)

Comment: Check updated version, should cater for your above comments.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little vague. But I think you want to use a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/conditional-ternary-operator-decrement-javascript) to check the values prior to binding in the case of there not being a value for one of the properties?

I think this can actually be achieved using an `*ngIf` like so; because when you think about it, there is no point in having an input field if there is nothing to bind to... right?

```
<input *ngIf="store ? (store[group.id] ? (store[group.id][person.id] ? true : false) : false) : false " 
    [(ngModel)]="store[group.id][person.id]">
```

This looks dreadful I know, however you could put this into a function and query that instead if you like.

Here is a Javascript example with a similar concept:

```js
// when exists:
let a = {b: {c: "hello"}};
let evaluation = a ? (a.b ? (a.b.c ? a.b.c : false) : false) : false;
console.log(evaluation);
// when does not exist:
a = {b: {d: "hello"}};
evaluation = a ? (a.b ? (a.b.c ? a.b.c : false) : false) : false;
console.log(evaluation);
```

Comment: You could simply do `*ngIf="store && store[group.id] && store[group.id][person.id]"`